# Global Environment Variables for Users & systemd

Tags: systemd, environment-variables

I have a set of environment variables that I need to be globally set for all users and all *systemd* services.  I don't want to have to specify them it two different locations.

I tried setting them `/etc/environment` and `/etc/profile.d`.  These both worked, but only for logged in users, not *systemd* services.

I tried setting them `/etc/default/init` and that didn't work for any process.

How can I set environment variables globally for all users and all services without having to specify them redundantly in multiple locations?

Distribution: Raspbian

Comment: Systemd intentionally runs services in a clean environment.

Answer (score 0):

DefaultEnvironment directive in system.conf does this for systemd.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html#DefaultEnvironment=